# Alamofire download destination error handling

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, download, alamofire

I'm using `Alamofire 4` to download file from server but sometimes **server response doesn't contain header File-Name** and I want to handle this error. **How to catch error** in `response.allHeaderFields["File-Name"] as! String` an rewrite `Error?` for `completion`?

```
func download(id: Int, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    print(id)
    var filePath: URL?
    var error: Error? = nil

    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, response in
        let fileName = response.allHeaderFields["File-Name"] as! String
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let documentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true)
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

        return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }

    Alamofire.download("\(serviceUrl)/\(language)/\(_controller)/DownloadFile", parameters: ["id": id], to: destination).responseData {
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(_):
            filePath = response.destinationURL
            break
        case .failure(let errorData):
            error = errorData
            break
        }

        completion(filePath, error)
    }
}
```

I'm using:

- Swift 4
- Alamofire 4.6
- iOS 11

Comment: use if-let or guard to handle nil values.

Comment: @TusharSharma how to pass error from `destination` to `Alamofire.download`?

Comment: pass error? Why you want this here? What is the error? It's better to exit out of function in case of error , instead passing it to download function? You have issue of nil values, and that is not an error.

Comment: @TusharSharma I want to handle error in `UIViewController` using `completion` closure. How could I do it?